# Convert List of strings to list of structs

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with two columns. The first is a column of unique IDs and the second is a colon delimited list of student scores( this is after loading it from a CSV without headers).

Is there any mechanism to convert the second column to a list of structs for further processing? Or a dynamic number of additional columns? I just need a way to do additional processing for the scores for each id i.e. calculate the mean for id `0000000003` which can't be done in the current output data format.

I.e.

```
+----------+-----------------------------+
|id        |scores                       |
+----------+-----------------------------+
|0000000003|brian,1.0:steve,2.3:allie,8.0|
|0783563078|chris,1.0                    |
|0783801254|michelle,1.0:vixon,2.3       |
+----------+-----------------------------+
```

into

```
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id        |scores                                                                    |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0000000003|[{student -> brian, score -> 1.0 } , {student -> steve, score -> 2.3 .... |
+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

or potentially something like this:

```
+----------+--------+------+--------+------+------+
|id        |student1|score1|student2|score3|etc...|
+----------+--------+------+--------+------+------+
|0000000003|        |      |        |      |      |
+----------+--------+------+--------+------+------+
```

I am just not sure of how to turn this data format into something that is processable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Approach 4 is possibly the shortest to get the average, but the other approaches allow you to extract the data as maps/structs.

#### Approach 1

An easily accessible approach may be to use [`str_to_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#str_to_map) which will convert your string value to a map. You could then use [`map_values`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#map_values(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to extract the scores eg

```scala
(
    df.withColumn(
        "score_map",
        expr("str_to_map(scores,':',',')")
    ).withColumn(
        "score_values",
        map_values(F.expr("str_to_map(scores,':',',')"))
    )
).show(false)
```

```
+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------------+
|id        |scores                       |score_map                                 |score_values   |
+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------------+
|0000000003|brian,1.0:steve,2.3:allie,8.0|{brian -> 1.0, steve -> 2.3, allie -> 8.0}|[1.0, 2.3, 8.0]|
|0783563078|chris,1.0                    |{chris -> 1.0}                            |[1.0]          |
|0783801254|michelle,1.0:vixon,2.3       |{michelle -> 1.0, vixon -> 2.3}           |[1.0, 2.3]     |
+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+---------------+
```

Since you are only interested in the average score, you may also use [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#explode(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to split the array returned by `map_values` into multiple rows before aggregating using `mean`. In the example below, I have included the original column `score` in the group by, however you may remove it and achieve the same results in your application.

```scala
(
    df.withColumn(
        "score_values",
        explode(map_values(F.expr("str_to_map(scores,':',',')")))
    )
    .groupBy("id","scores") // you may remove "scores" from here to only have the id
    .agg(
        mean("score_values").alias("score_avg")
    )
).show(false)
```

```
+----------+-----------------------------+-----------------+
|id        |scores                       |score_avg        |
+----------+-----------------------------+-----------------+
|0000000003|brian,1.0:steve,2.3:allie,8.0|3.766666666666667|
|0783801254|michelle,1.0:vixon,2.3       |1.65             |
|0783563078|chris,1.0                    |1.0              |
+----------+-----------------------------+-----------------+
```

#### Approach 2

If you prefer to use a `struct`, you may use `split`, [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) and [`named_struct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#named_struct) in spark-sql to convert your data in the desired `struct` eg

```scala
val df2=(
    df.withColumn(
        "score_struct",
        expr("transform(split(scores,':'), x-> named_struct('student',split(x,',')[0],'score',split(x,',')[1])       )")
    )
)
df2.printSchema()
df2.show(false)
```

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- scores: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score_struct: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- student: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- score: string (nullable = true)

+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|id        |scores                       |score_struct                              |
+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
|0000000003|brian,1.0:steve,2.3:allie,8.0|[{brian, 1.0}, {steve, 2.3}, {allie, 8.0}]|
|0783563078|chris,1.0                    |[{chris, 1.0}]                            |
|0783801254|michelle,1.0:vixon,2.3       |[{michelle, 1.0}, {vixon, 2.3}]           |
+----------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------+
```

We can again, `explode` to split the list of values in each row into multiple rows before using `mean` to determine the average eg.

```
df2=(
    df.withColumn(
        "score_struct",
        expr("explode(transform(split(scores,':'), x-> named_struct('student',split(x,',')[0],'score',split(x,',')[1])       ))")
    )
    .groupBy("id")
    .agg(
        mean("score_struct.score").alias("score_avg")
    )
)
df2.printSchema()
df2.show(truncate=False)
```

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score_avg: double (nullable = true)

+----------+-----------------+
|id        |score_avg        |
+----------+-----------------+
|0000000003|3.766666666666667|
|0783563078|1.0              |
|0783801254|1.65             |
+----------+-----------------+
```

#### Approach 3

You could simply use approach 2 only extract your desired values i.e. the scores, before calculating the average eg:

```scala
val df2=(
    df.withColumn(
        "score",
        expr("explode(transform(split(scores,':'), x-> split(x,',')[1]       ))")
    )
    .groupBy("id")
    .agg(
        mean("score").alias("score_avg")
    )
)
df2.printSchema()
df2.show(false)
```

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- score_avg: double (nullable = true)

+----------+-----------------+
|id        |score_avg        |
+----------+-----------------+
|0000000003|3.766666666666667|
|0783563078|1.0              |
|0783801254|1.65             |
+----------+-----------------+
```

#### Approach 4

This approach uses `split` and [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#aggregate(expr:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,initialValue:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,merge:(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,org.apache.spark.sql.Column)=%3Eorg.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to extract the sum of each row before dividing by the number of entries to find the average

```scala
df2=(
    df.withColumn(
        "scores",
        split("scores",':')
    )
    .withColumn(
        "scores",
        expr("aggregate(scores,cast(0 as double), (acc,x) -> acc + split(x,',')[1])") / size("scores")
    )
)
df2.printSchema()
df2.show(false)
```

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- scores: double (nullable = true)

+----------+-----------------+
|id        |scores           |
+----------+-----------------+
|0000000003|3.766666666666667|
|0783563078|1.0              |
|0783801254|1.65             |
+----------+-----------------+
```